# I can't populate a JComboBox with an ArrayList

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have two classes, one has an ArrayList called "clanovi" which is populated by data from SQL database and I want to display that data in the "clanComboBox" in another class. I have been trying for two days but I can't figure it out.

Class with the list:

```
String cnnString;
String user;
String password;

public ArrayList<String> clanovi = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    
    return clanovi;
}

public void Connect(String cnnString, String user, String password){
    
    this.cnnString = cnnString;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
    
    ResultSet res = null;
    
    
    
    try {
        
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(cnnString, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connection successful");
        
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
        
        String sql = "select Ime, Prezime from Clanovi";
        res = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        
        while(res.next()) {
            
            clanovi.add(res.getString("Ime") + " " + res.getString("Prezime"));
        }
        
        System.out.println(clanovi);
        
        
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("An unexpected error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The GUI class with the combobox:

public class PosuditiFilmFrame implements ActionListener{

```
SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection();
JFrame posuditiFilmFrame = new JFrame();
JButton posuditiFilmButton = new JButton();
JComboBox clanoviComboBox = new JComboBox();
JComboBox filmoviComboBox = new JComboBox();
JLabel clanLabel = new JLabel("Clan:");
JLabel filmLabel = new JLabel("Film:");

ArrayList<String> cBox = con.getList();



PosuditiFilmFrame(){
    
    posuditiFilmButton = new JButton();
    posuditiFilmButton.setBounds(200, 270, 200, 50);
    posuditiFilmButton.addActionListener(this);;
    posuditiFilmButton.setText("Posuditi Film");
    posuditiFilmButton.setFocusable(false);
    
    clanLabel.setBounds(50, 50, 70, 50);
    clanLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    
    filmLabel.setBounds(50, 125, 70, 50);
    filmLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    
    clanoviComboBox.setBounds(150, 50, 300, 50);
    filmoviComboBox.setBounds(150, 125, 300, 50);
    
    
    posuditiFilmFrame.setTitle("Posuditi Film");
    posuditiFilmFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    posuditiFilmFrame.setLayout(null);
    posuditiFilmFrame.setSize(600, 400);
    posuditiFilmFrame.setVisible(true);
    posuditiFilmFrame.add(posuditiFilmButton);
    posuditiFilmFrame.add(clanoviComboBox);
    posuditiFilmFrame.add(filmoviComboBox);
    posuditiFilmFrame.add(clanLabel);
    posuditiFilmFrame.add(filmLabel);
    
    }


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    if(e.getSource()==posuditiFilmButton) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Film je posuden");
    }
}
```

Of course, I also want the data to be displayed in that combobox

Comment: `for(String s : cBox)clanoviComboBox.addItem(s);`

Comment: I tried that but the combobox doesn't display anything....

Comment: Maybe you don't have data in you database, because for me it works just fine with some test data

Comment: I have data. When I do System.out.print(clanovi) in the class with the ArrayList, it prints out the data on the console. But if I do the same for the "cBox" in the other class it prints "[]" So the "clanovi" ArrayList is populated but for some reason, the "cBox" isn't.

Comment: probably cause by the order in which the classes are instantiated. Make sure to create `PosuditiFilmFrame` after calling the `Connect` method

Comment: This is my main method: public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  ConnectionConfig conn = new ConnectionConfig();
  conn.Connect(DatabaseType.Sql);
  
  new GlavniIzbornikFrame();
 }
}

I'm calling "glavniIzbornikFrame which has a button that opens posuditiFilmFrame but before that I have called the Connect method

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious but i just started Java and I'm trying to figure it out